# Get X, Y position in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

In JS, we could use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` to get element's X and Y coordinates.
But what if we want to know the X,Y coordinates of an element in canvas

The closet thing I could think about is  `CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath()` to check without a point exists in the shape. Is there a built-in function or any way to get X and Y coordinates of a shape in canvas?

For example,

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Is there a way I get the top/left coordiates of the black rect?

Any answers will be appreicated.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates you use to specify the `rect` begin with the x/y pair for the top-left corner of the `rect` *relative to the canvas*.

One would expect the screen coordinates to be obtained by adding the `rect`'s x value to the `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left` value for the screen x coordinate, and the y value added to the `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top` value would give the y coordinate.

If you are adding shapes to the rect using js, it would be relatively easy to keep track of the top left of each in variables and calculate screen coordinates as you go.

as a rough and ready means of (manually) obtaining a reasonable estimate of any point, a simple click `eventListener` could be used to report coordinates of points you click on:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.fill();

canvas.addEventListener ('click', event => {
  console.log(`x: ${event.screenX}, y: ${event.screenY}`)
})
```

```html
<canvas width="200px" height="200px" style="background:red"></canvas>
```

Comment: The rect x, y value I don't know

Comment: OK, where is the data coming from? We have to devise a way of reading the 10,10 in your example.

Comment: I am dealing with chart.js where I need to know the coordinates for a lienTo. I don't know the coordinates :(

Comment: I see. yes, that may be a problem. I've had a quick search and can't find ways of reading values set by canvas methods. I'll have a think. A dirty estimate could be made by adding a js click listener and reporting the values for screen clicks, would something like that help or do you need pixel accuracy?

Comment: Actually, screenX/clientX/pageX is all the thing I have tested before posted the question (it doesn't work because chart.js coordinates is different, it is not based on screen,but based on the chart I guess), but I just finally figured out use a chart.js way. I may not accpet your answer because they doesn't help me (but +1 to express my appreication )Thank you for the help:)

Comment: well done for working it out, and thanks for the upvote, much appreciated. Is your solution short enough to outline here? I'm curious and it might be of interest to others in future. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bit too specific answer. What I am doing is to simulate the effect lke yahoo stock website/ apple stock and I want to draw a horzontal line when hovering and a following div, I am struggled with prevent the div go outside the chart, but chart.js calculate width will include the width for y axis label which give me a lot of trouble, but I finally solve it:)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite simple. Where you make you're box like this;
`ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);`, Instead do this;

```
var x = 10;
var y = 10;

ctx.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
```

Then you can move it however you like *and* know where it is,   e.g.
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "x:" + x + "y:" + y;` at the end of your code and then put `<p id="demo"></p>` in the html part. If you want to it to update in real-time try using  `requestAnimationFrame`, but try to put it in a function first.